# Figures are not nicely centered between paragraphs

Tags: floats, parskip

I use my floats with `[h]`. When I use this command:

```
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
```

it does set the separation between the above text and figure to 0 but not between the figure and the paragraph afterwords. I tried also to not change anything and load the `parskip` package. Didn't work. I've seen a lot of questions about this topic but no real answer... My figures are not nicely centered between text...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\unframedsolutions
%\printanswers
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newgeometry{left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

This is the upper paragraph which has less space between this text and lower figure.

\begin{figure*}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=5mm]
\path node[rectangle,draw=green,fill=green!8,inner sep=.70cm] {\parbox{\textwidth-1.4cm-\fboxrule}{

\question[2] What is the first question?
\begin{solutionorlines}[4cm]
This box is smaller than when the solutions are not printed. How do I make this the same dimension as when answers are not printed?
\end{solutionorlines}
}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}

This is the lower paragraph which has more space between this text and above figure.

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be a lot clearer if you provided a complete small document that shows the problem, otherwise, is `\parskip` zero? do you use the figure between paragraphs or mid-paragraph?

Comment: Hi and welcome, if you go into that much trouble, it would be much easier to use a minipage or parbox and prevent floating from the start.

Comment: But why does LaTeX do that? I have plenty of space on my sheet. Just center my figure between 2 paragraphs...

Comment: You simply don't need `figure` (nor `figure*`).

Comment: If you remove figure than the picture goes to the right of the screen. Also i use the [h] in the figure environment to prevent it from floating.

Comment: Do not use figure environments in the exam class!

Answer (score 1):

Speculating without a MWE, but here we go ...

If you set `\intextsep` to zero, you still get an interline space after your figure. You can suppress this by setting `\prevdepth` to `-1000pt` (see chapter 15 of [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\rule{4cm}{4cm}
\end{figure}
\prevdepth=-1000pt
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: nospace]

It's hard to think of a good reason for doing this.

Comment: This command doesn't work in horizontal mode. Yes I want something like your MWE. I want to adjust maybe later on a variable, but my pictures should be nicely in the middle of two paragraphs...

Comment: @bert --- *you* need to provide an example showing exactly what it is that *you* want.

Comment: When I put this after my figure it indeed gives the same amount of space before and after my figure but I get errors... You know how to solve it?
\vadjust
\prevdepth-1000pt